# Absolute value less than some value

Tags: inequality, fractions, absolute-value

This is a noob question. If, 
$$\biggm| \frac{1}{2} - e \biggm | \le n$$
Then how do I get the following? 
$$e \le \frac{1}{2} + n$$

Answer (score 1):

Having $\lvert a - b \rvert \leq c$ is basically the same as $\lvert b - a \rvert \leq c$.

You can also think of distances. The distance between $a$ and $b$ is less than $c$. If you imagine dots on the number line and keep the distance thingy in mind it should be very easy to see.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if $\dfrac{1}{2} - n \leq e$, the first equation holds.

Plot the graph of the absolut value function. All values of $x$ such that $|x|\leq n$ lie in the interval $[-n,n]$, i.e.
$$x\in[-n,n] \ \iff \ |x|\leq n.$$

Substitute the right hand side of the equation where $x$ is to get 
$$| e + \dfrac{1}{2}| \leq n \ \iff \ e + \dfrac{1}{2} \in [-n,n] \ \iff -n\leq e + \dfrac{1}{2} \leq n.$$ For solving it, you need to solve both inequalities:
$$-n\leq e + \dfrac{1}{2}$$
$$e + \dfrac{1}{2} \leq n.$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to know that
$$[a-b|\le c\iff b-c\le a\le b+c,$$
and remener tha $|a-b|=|b-a|.